# Java module referencing inside Android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to compile Java module in Android Studio.
I'm also referencing android.jar in the module. So, yes, module is supposed to be Java, but uses android.jar as compilation reference.
The version SDK for this android.jar is irrelevant (I think, but it is 19 something).

(You might ask why if I need android.jar don't I use Android module instead of Java?, well it is intermediary step to restructure our Android project).

The problem I'm facing: 
[image]

error: cannot find symbol variable SDK_INT

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
    compile project(':ATTLogger')
    compile project(':BandwidthController')
    compile project(':iwpstack')
    compile files('libs/android.jar')
}
```

You see – IT doesn't want to recognize some… code clearly present in the android.jar.
And yes it sees import android.os.Build; and doesn't complain about it.

Here is my bukd.gradle:

Please help if you happened to solve this nuisance I've wasted half a day on.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any calls to Android API in that project?

Comment: Sure, specially it shouts on: Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH

Comment: I'm skeptical as to whether or not you're doing something that makes sense, but at any rate, I was able to create a plain Java module and access `Build` constants in it, so it works in some cases. You'll need to add more details to your question to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a Java only code (without any calls to Android API) then you can make it a JAR without adding a dependency to android.jar. Otherwise, if you have calls to Android API, you should make it AAR module.
From http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-build.html#projectModules :

- Java library modules contain reusable code. The build system generates a JAR package for Java library modules.
- Android library modules contain reusable Android-specific code and resources. The build system generates an AAR (Android ARchive) package for library modules.
- Android application modules contain application code and may depend on library modules, although many Android apps consists of only one application module. The build system generates an APK package for application modules.

So to fix your issue, you should skip this "intermediary step" and make it an Android module right away.

Comment: Thanks. But why android.jar is different from any other jar that I compile against?

Comment: I am not sure, but my guess is that there is more than android.jar for a module to be Android.